# generating a quote when clicking, then changing background based on the random quote that is generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a `var = quotes [{"author": "string", "quote": "string"}];`
before all this, its just super long so I didn't post it.

Right now the click generates the random quote, and removes the header which is perfect.

What I want is if the "author" of the generated quote is a certain author, the background of body will change.

The problem is, this doesn't happen on click

```
function randomQuote() {
  var random = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

  $("#thisquote").text(random.quote);

  $("#thisauthor").text("-" +random.author);


    if ($(quotes[random].author)  === "Kramer") {
      $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/kramer.jpg'"); 
    }
    else if (quotes[random].author === "George"){
      $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/george.jpg'"); 
    }
    else if (quotes[random]["author"] === "Elaine"){
      $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/elaine.jpg'"); 
    }
    else if (quotes[random]["author"] === "Jerry"){
      $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/jerry.jpg'"); 
    }
    else{
      $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/bg.jpg'"); 
    }

};



function removeHeader() {
  $("#header").remove();
}

$('.btn').click(function() {
  removeHeader();
  randomQuote();

});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues: `changeBackground()` doesn't exist where it's being used, and you had an extra `$(...)` around the first `quotes[random].author`, and every instance of `quotes[random].author` should just be `random.author`.

All three issues are fixed below:

```
function randomQuote() {
  var random = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

  $("#thisquote").text(random.quote);

  $("#thisauthor").text("-" +random.author);

  if (random.author  === "Kramer") {
    $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/kramer.jpg'"); 
  }
  else if (random.author === "George"){
    $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/george.jpg'"); 
  }
  else if (random.author === "Elaine"){
    $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/elaine.jpg'"); 
  }
  else if (random.author === "Jerry"){
    $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/jerry.jpg'"); 
  }
  else {
    $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/bg.jpg'"); 
  }
}    

function removeHeader() {
  $("#header").remove();
}

$('.btn').click(function() {
  removeHeader();
  randomQuote();
});
```

Just for fun, here's perhaps an easier (at least shorter) way to set the background to what you want:

```
var backgrounds = {
  Kramer: 'kramer.jpg',
  George: 'george.jpg',
  Elaine: 'elaine.jpg',
  Jerry: 'jerry.jpg',
}

$("body").css(
  "background-image",
  "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url('file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/" +
  (backgrounds[random.author] || "bg.jpg"));
```

Comment: I will edit my code with the updates, it still doesn't work. I think the problem lies in my notation. 

Sorry for the messy code, first time on here, won't happen again. 

the problem is it will not change the background

Comment: Then please tell us what the problem is. Are there any errors in the console? Does something happen different from what you expected? What else have you tried and learned so far?

Comment: the problem is in my notation, I get this error

script.js:151 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined

Comment: Oh, I also noticed you have `$(quotes[random].author)` instead of `quotes[random].author`. That should probably only make "Kramer" quotes fail, though, since the rest look okay.

Comment: got it, just fixed the $

Comment: @WillDiFruscio Ah! Actually, my most recent comment should address that.

Comment: I fixed the $ but its still getting the same error. I also tried using if ($("thisauthor") === "kramer") to no avail

Comment: @WillDiFruscio See my most recent update. Three issues found so far. :-)

Comment: I GOT IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! got rid of the quotes, just had it go for random.author, since quotes is outside it probably is only read once?

Comment: `var random = quotes[...];` <-- so random is one of the quotes (the one you picked at random). Then if you try to do `quotes[random]`, you're doing something like `quotes[{"quote": "foo", "author": "bar"}]`, which will just return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not shunt the background image URL into the quotes array?

**Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7r3ttLst/**

```js
var quotes = [
  {
    "author": "Kramer", 
    "quote": "Kramer Quote",
    "bg": "http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/kramer-619924.jpeg"
  },
  {
    "author": "George", 
    "quote": "Kramer Quote",
    "bg": "http://photos.oes.org/albums/userpics/10002/TickBiteHealing.jpg"
  },
  {
    "author": "Other", 
    "quote": "Other Quote",
    "bg": ""
  },
];

function randomQuote() {
    var random = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    var bg = '';

    $("#thisquote").text(random.quote);
    $("#thisauthor").text("-" +random.author);

    if (random.bg.length) {
        bg = random.bg;
    } else {
        bg = 'file:C:/Users/user/Desktop/freecodecamp/random quote/images/bg.jpg';
    }

    $("body").css("background-image", "linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url("+bg+")"); 
}
```

Comment: This is great, this is how I am going to do the updated version!! Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!